# How to extend linux display(Ubuntu 19) onto a windows 32 bit

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I was considering to use my old laptop as a second monitor. Although, I have been able to do this on windows using spacedesk but did not find any alternative for it on Linux. 
I currently have windows on my old laptop but won't mind dual booting another os. 
Any suggestions on how to get this done?

> ROG Strix III - primary laptop
>
> Dell inspiron 1525 - Old Laptop